# Angular2 - get data from service on init with Switchmap

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing a term search with Angular 2. It's about the same code used in the Heroes tutorial.

My service :

```
search(term: string = null, page: string = null, limit: string = null): Observable<Bibliographie[]> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    if (term) params.set('q', term);
    if (page) params.set('_page', page);
    if (limit) params.set('_limit', limit);
    return this.http
        .get('http://localhost:3000/bibliographie', {search: params})
        .map(response => response.json() as Bibliographie[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

My component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.bibliographies = this.searchTerms
        .debounceTime(300)
        .switchMap(term => term
            ? this.bibliographieSearchService.search(term)
            : this.bibliographieSearchService.search(null, "1", "20"))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.of<Bibliographie[]>([]);
        });
}
```

It works well if I type some text in the input dialog. Problem is, I want to have some results before typing anything. In the code above, I added the line

```
: this.bibliographieSearchService.search(null, "1", "20"))
```

for this purpose, hoping that a page of results would be shown when term is null. But it only works when I clear the input dialog. I also tried to load the data on init with another service function. But then, the search does not work anymore.

Any idea?

Comment: For this to work you need to change the query.

Comment: Problem is: on init, no data is loaded from the service with my code. I tried to load data directly in ngOnInit() with another function, but then the term search does not work anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that `this.searchTerms` is probably an Observable of `valueChanges`, so until the value inside the input does not change, any event is being emitted.

Let's say you want to trigger the search each time that the input is being focused, and also each time that the value is changing.

So, in this case, what do you need is to listen to the focus event as well, to be able to emit a value when the focus event is triggered by the input. But you always need to take the last value that `valueChanged` emitted. In this case a [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-combineLatest) operator would make sense, so you listen to both the focus and the value change. The `combineLatest` operator emits the latest values of each source Observables, so even in when the `focus` event is the one that emits, you will receive the last one from `this.searchTerms`.

To be able to listen to the focus event, you will need to use @ViewChild on your input, to get a reference in your component.

```
// html
<input ... #myComponent>

// ts

export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('myComponent') myComponent;
  myComponentFocus$: Observable;

  constructor () {}
}
```

Then you can create an observable of the focus event of your input in the ngOnInit function,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myComponentFocus = Observable.fromEvent(this.myComponent.nativeElement, 'focus')
  ...
}
```

Now your bibliographies would be something like:

```
this.bibliographies = Observable.combineLatest(this.searchTerms, this.myComponentFocus)
    .debounceTime(300)
    .switchMap(([focusEvt, term]) => term
        ? this.bibliographieSearchService.search(term)
        : this.bibliographieSearchService.search(null, "1", "20"))
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.of<Bibliographie[]>([]);
    });
```

**BUT**, there is still a problem with this solution. `combineLatest` **won't** emit until all the Observables combined have emitted any value, so our this.bibliographies will still need for the value change to emit before emitting anything.

To solve that, we can create an Observable of **null**, and then concat `this.searchTerms` to this null Observable. This means the new Observable will have a value (null) from the beginning, so when `focus` event is emitted, `this.bibliographies` Observable will emit as well.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.myComponentFocus = Observable.fromEvent(this.myComponent.nativeElement, 'focus')

      this.searchTermsWithNull = Observable.of(null).concat(this.searchTerms)

      this.bibliographies =     Observable.combineLatest(this.searchTermsWithNull, this.myComponentFocus)
        .debounceTime(300)
        .switchMap(([focusEvt, term]) => term
            ? this.bibliographieSearchService.search(term)
            : this.bibliographieSearchService.search(null, "1", "20"))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.of<Bibliographie[]>([]);
        });
      }
```

If, for instance, you only want to use the first focus of the event and not all the others, you can add a `take(1)` to the focus event observable.

Comment: You are a genius. The searchTermsWithNull alone just worked!

Answer (score 0):

The last element of the answer above worked without the focus part (I think because there is no child element)! This is my new ngOnInit function:

```
...
private searchTermsWithNull;
...

ngOnInit(): void {

        this.searchTermsWithNull = Observable.of(null).concat(this.searchTerms);

        this.bibliographies = this.searchTermsWithNull
            .debounceTime(300)
            .switchMap(term => term
                ? this.bibliographieSearchService.search(term)
                : this.bibliographieSearchService.search(null, "1", "20"))
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                return Observable.of<Bibliographie[]>([]);
            });
    }
```